# Magento - change the width that RWD theme turns mobile

Tags: theme, rwd

Hello i have modified a RWD theme for my store but have found that on ipads in portrait mode have turned mobile.

I want to change the width that RWD changes to a mobile view with dropdown menus to be slightly less than the ipad portrait width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento RWD theme breakpoints are defined in `_var.scss` at line 49:

`$bp-xsmall: 479px;
$bp-small: 599px;
$bp-medium: 770px;
$bp-large: 979px;
$bp-xlarge: 1199px;`

You have to change the `$bp-medium` value.
After that remember to update `app.js` at line 34 and to recompile css files

Comment: Thanks this is what i need! However i didn't even notice that this template was Sass and have been modifiying the styles.css (not to familiar with sass and scss until this morning). So do i recompile the _var.scss using ssh like so: sass _var.scss ../css/styles.css and overwrite my old styles sheet or does it go somewhere else? Thanks

Comment: i think it will overwrite the existing css file